# Set interval time based on equation?

Tags: javascript

How can I divide a post.length variable from a for loop and send it to a set interval and replace the millis with of the setinterval time. I tried several things.

```
const soundtrigger = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8];
const randSoundtrigger = soundtrigger[Math.floor(Math.random() * soundtrigger.length)];

var  timer = (post.length / 540);

console.log(timer);

....

    console.log("Posts received with hashtag: ".cyan + posts.length);
    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        let post = posts[i];

    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
        console.log("end");
    });
  }
```

.......

```
setInterval(function() {
    var msg = {
        address: "/play/note",
        args: [
            {
                    // midi note value 
                        type: "i",
                        value: randSoundtrigger
            },
            {   // amp value a float to send decimal numbers
                type: "f",
                value: 1.5
            },
                {   // sustain value
                        type: "f",
                        value: 2
                    }
        ]
    };

    console.log("Sending message", msg.address, msg.args, "to", udpPort.options.remoteAddress + ":" + udpPort.options.remotePort);
    udpPort.send(msg);
}, timer);   =>>>>>> This timer value should be the result of post.length / 540
```

The goal i’m going for it to send a number between 1 - 8 (0 is not allowed in the osc receiving program ;))
I get the post length every 10 minutes and that value should be divided by 9 nine minutes = 540.
The outcome should be the setinterval time to send the message.

Is this possible??

Comment: `setInterval` creates a new interval. You can imagine it like creating a new alarm clock. You obviously don't want to create a new alarm clock each time. Try `setTimeout` + recursive functions

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness of the comment above, this is what I mean by `setTimeout` + recursive function:

```js
function tick(index = 0) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Called after ${index} seconds`);
    if (index < 5) tick(index + 1);
  }, index * 1000);
}

tick();
```

You can substitute `index*1000` with `array[index]*1000`

```js
const array = [3, 2, 1];
function tick(index = 0) {
  setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Called after ${array[index]} seconds`);
      if (index < array.length - 1) tick(index + 1);
  }, array[index] * 1000);
}

tick();
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the post.length out of it's function? Otherwise indeed the timeout is a lot better!

Comment: The posts.length (aka array.length) is inside the if statement. It's used as stop condition for the recursion

Comment: So you are saying that you can't get the array.length out of the if statement? There must be a way to use that data, not??